# How can I exclude source file metadata from output when compiling?

Tags: gcc, compilation, metadata, executable, binaryfiles

For example:

```
$ gcc -O3 foobar.c -o foobar
$ grep 'foobar\.c' foobar
Binary file foobar matches
```

How can I exclude such unnecessary and revealing metadata from the output of `gcc` and other compilers? It appears regardless of whether the output is an assembly file, object file, or executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

man strip(1)

```
> strip -s a.out
```

Comment: Can an I `strip` an object file and still be able to link it after? I didn't really intend to strip actual function labels.

Comment: @Matt Yes, I believe so. `strip --strip-debug aaa.o` shall remove debug info but leave function labels intact. You might check symbols in .o using `nm` or `readelf` utility. Also for shared objects you might want to check `--strip-unneeded` option